# Notice: Array to string conversion in "path of php file" on line 64

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oracle

PHP CODE -:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$rows =0;
$fp = fopen("leave1.csv","r");
if($fp){
    while(!feof($fp)){
          $content = fgets($fp);
      if($content)    $rows++;
    }
}
fclose($fp);
//echo $rows;
$_SESSION['rows'] = $rows;
?>
<?php
$row = 1;
$row1=0;
if (($handle = fopen("leave1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
        {
            $array[$row1][$c] = $data[$c];
        }
        $_SESSION['num'] = $num; 
        $row1 = $row1 + 1;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
<?php

$num = $_SESSION['num'];
$rows = $_SESSION['rows'];

for($rs=0;$rs<$rows;$rs++)
{
    for($cs=0;$cs<$num;$cs++)
    {
        echo $array[$rs][$cs];
        echo " ";
    }
    echo "<br />\n";
}
?>

<?php
$connection = oci_connect("SIEBELT2","SIEBELT2$1","DS2D");
$num = $_SESSION['num'];
$rows = $_SESSION['rows'];
for($rs=0;$rs<$rows;$rs++)
{
    $main_query=oci_parse($connection,"INSERT INTO ROTTAN(NAME,ROLLNO) VALUES('$array[$rs][0]','$array[$rs][1]')");

         if(!$main_query)
         {
            echo "Error in preparing the statement";
            exit;
         }
         oci_execute($main_query);
}
$connection = oci_connect("SIEBELT2","SIEBELT2$1","DS2D");
?>


</body>
</html>
```

This is a code to insert records from excel sheet into oracle database.

In first php script i am reading the no of rows of the excel sheet.

In second php script i am storing contents of excel sheet into a 2D php array.

In third php script i am trying to upload 2d array into oracle database via INSERT INTO SQL command.
ROTTAN is the table name
NAME and ROLLNO are the two fields of the table

On running the php i get the following error on line 64 which is-:

```
$main_query=oci_parse($connection,"INSERT INTO ROTTAN(NAME,ROLLNO) VALUES('$array[$rs][0]','$array[$rs][1]')");
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website_LMS\bulk1.php on line 64

Comment: You're trying to convert an array to a string in the query itself. Convert the array into a string first, then place that in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly brackets are your friend when inserting variables into double quoted strings:

```
$main_query=oci_parse($connection,"INSERT INTO ROTTAN(NAME,ROLLNO) VALUES('{$array[$rs][0]}','{$array[$rs][1]}')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$main_query=oci_parse($connection,"INSERT INTO ROTTAN(NAME,ROLLNO) VALUES('{$array[$rs][0]}','{$array[$rs][1]}')");
```

Notice the curly braces around each variable. PHP can't work out a complex expression when used in a string. Alternatively you could do this:

```
$main_query=oci_parse($connection,"INSERT INTO ROTTAN(NAME,ROLLNO) VALUES('" . $array[$rs][0] . "','" . $array[$rs][1] . "')");
```